# RSpec test for webhook controllers with basic auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-grape

In my Rails/Grape app I created a webhook controller which receive JSON from CMS webhook. I'm just wondering how to test it in RSpec if I don't have any params (I guess I don't need it because I only receive JSON from webhook).

My webhook controller (it works well):

```
module Cms
  class Webhook < Base
    desc 'Take the CMS webhook'

    http_basic do |user, password|
      user == ENV['USER'] && password == ENV['PASSWORD']
    end

    post :receive do
      params
    end
  end
end
```

I was trying to like:

```
describe Cms::Webhooks, type: :request do
  subject(:call) { post endpoint, params: params, as: :json }

  let(:endpoint) { '/api/cms/webhooks/receive' }

  let(:params) do
    {
      some: 'some pass'
    }
  end

  it 'returns a successful response' do
    call
    expect(response).to be_successful
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_successful
   expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00007f9058e43e60 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00007f9058e43de8>, @mon_data_..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.successful?` to return true, got false
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```rb
describe Cms::Webhooks, type: :request do
  subject(:call) { post endpoint, params: params, as: :son, headers: headers }

  let(:endpoint) { '/api/cms/webhooks/receive' }

  let(:params) do
    {
      some: 'some pass'
    }
  end

  let(:headers) do
    {
      'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('your_username', 'your_password')
    }
  end  

  it 'returns a successful response' do
    call
    expect(response).to be_successful
  end
end
```

Ref https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html